# I can not add a dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, gradle

I'm new in Android Studio and i want to add dependency to custom view (https://github.com/glomadrian/dashed-circular-progress) in my project. I downloaded *.arr file from Maven repository and imported it like a AAR module. But i can't compile my project because there are some exceptions with this custom view: `ClassNotFoundException`. Could someone explain me step by step how to correctly add dependencies from maven rep? or there are some problems with this DashedCircularProgress.aar? Thanks.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahryk94gmail.mibandsdk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.glomadrian:DashedCircularProgress:1.0@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the project description you have to add the following code to `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.glomadrian:DashedCircularProgress:1.0@aar'
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Also you can use [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io) and download the dependency right from GitHub.

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.glomadrian:dashed-circular-progress:59d245a'
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Android Studio can't find this dependency in rep.

Comment: Yep, custom Maven repo is needed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.glomadrian:DashedCircularProgress:1.0

Comment: Works for me. Do you have `@aar` at the end of dependency definition?

Comment: my gradle file differs

Comment: Add lines from my answer to the end of your file and everything should work fine.

Comment: Line 32 is `compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')`.

Comment: I added jitpack.io configuration which works too. If you still have any problems with using this dependency create an empty project and try once again. If the error in some other part of your configuration you should create another question.